# Pre-Filled/Sender's Tabs on a Template

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have a sender's/pre-filled tab inside a template. I'm trying to send this template using C# api. Now I'm using the below code to fill this tab while sending a envelope using this template

`var env = new EnvelopeDefinition { TemplateId = templateId };

```
        var prefillTabs = new PrefillTabs()
        {
            TextTabs = new List<Text>()
            {
                new Text()
                {
                    DocumentId = "1",
                    TabLabel = "business-details.BusinessInformation.BusinessName",
                    Value = "PreFill: BusinessName"
                }
            }
        };

        var tabs = new Tabs()
        {
            PrefillTabs = prefillTabs
        };

        var signerRole = new TemplateRole
        {
            Email = signer.Email,
            Name = signer.Email,
            RoleName = templateRoleName,
            Tabs = tabs
        };

       env.TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole> { signerRole };
        env.Status = "sent";

       // send this envelop using EnvelopApiClient
      await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(accountId, env);`
```

Envelop is sent but the problem is prefilled tab is not populated and also SignHere field is not visible in the sent envelope. I have spent a lot of time figuring it out but couldn't figure it out. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you do this from the web app? meaning without the API, just create a template and popular these prefill fields in an envelope created from a template?

Comment: Sorry you're having this trouble. Please use [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to obtain the log of your request. Then update (edit) your question with the log. Thank you.

Comment: @InbarGazit - Yes from UI it's working.

Comment: @LarryK - Sure let me first try the below answer then I will check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

[DocuSign pre-fill tabs](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-customize-your-envelopes-pre-fill-fields) are NOT associated with a recipient or a role. So the code you have cannot work because you have them assigned to the recipient (role) in your template.
What you need to do is either:

1. Create the fields/tabs you want in the template itself. They will be passed to any envelope created from the template. (Downside - every envelope created from this template will have them).
2. Add the prefill fields with code like this after the envelope is already created (Downside - need two API calls instead of one):
   [![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add(
    "Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); 
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient); 
PrefillTabs prefillTabs = new PrefillTabs(); 
prefillTabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>(); 
prefillTabs.TextTabs.Add(
    new Text { PageNumber = "1", DocumentId = "1", Value = "MyValue" }); 
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(); 
tabs.PrefillTabs = prefillTabs;
envelopesApi.CreateDocumentTabs(accountId, envelopeId, "1", tabs);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. Actually, I will have to make 3 calls. 1. Create an envelope in the draft. 2. Prefill tab data with the above code. 3. Send the envelope in the draft.

Comment: Didn't work :( Once I create an envelope in the draft and then try to send it using envelope api update call. It returns an error that recipients are missing. Although I have filled out this in the template role.

Comment: Not sure how you did the templateRoles and what the envelope looks like. It may be it's not set correctly.

Comment: roleName must match whats in the template.